# How many n-digit sequences have exactly k 0's?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, combinations

I think my homework question is missing some info.

Ive posted the question exactly as stated.

Am I correct that there is an error in the question?

Comment: You'll be looking for an expression for how many sequences, say $s$, in terms of $n$ and $k$. Try out a few specific values...

Comment: Technically, the question is a bit ambiguous. I would assume a base $10$ number system.

Comment: Ya I know how to do it for binary,ternary, etc. But it does not specify what type of sequence. Is the problem solvable without specification?

Comment: You could express it in terms of the base of the number system, call it $b$, but this should really be explicit in the question.

Comment: Assume the base is 2.  Then once you pick the $k$ positions where the zeros must go, the sequence is uniquely determined.  In how many ways can you pick $k$ positions from $n$ positions?  Now assume the base is $b$. Then each of the remaining $n-k$ positions can be filled in $(b-1)$ ways.

Comment: Thanks Ashwin. Im going to assume base 10. I know exactly how to do it, no worries.

Comment: Okay the idea of making it solvable for any type of sequence is much better. I have done it with base "b". Thanks everyone.